# Python remove method removes element from both lists

Tags: python, list

When I run the code below:

```py
a=[0,1,2,3]
t=a
t.remove(3)
print(a)
```

it gives me a result of `[0,1,2]` even though I didn't use the `remove()` method for list `a`. Why does it happen?

Comment: I wanted to refer to a tutorial, but the page has been removed.

Comment: Because you didn't make a copy, you just have 2 names pointing to the same object in memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists in python are mutable objects and hence when you assigned t = a,
you created list 't' which is reference to list 'a'. Both lists refer to the same memory location.

### Original list

```
a=[0,1,2,3]
id(a) # gives unique number which points to memory location
>> 60528136
```

### assigning to t

```
t = a
id(t)
>> 60528136
```

The result shows same number which signifies that both lists refer to the same memory location. So any modification on list 'a' would be reflected in list 't' and vice-versa.
To avoid this create a copy.

```
t = a[::]
```

or

```
t = a.copy()
id(t)
>>60571720
```

Answer (score 2):

Because list(and dicts) are pass by reference in Python. You have to shallow copy the list if you don't want it to happen like this:

```
t=a[:]
```

or

```
t=a.copy()
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out the Python docs on Programming FAQ [here](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html).

> ### [Why did changing list ‘y’ also change list ‘x’?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-did-changing-list-y-also-change-list-x)
>
> There are two factors that produce this result:
>
> 1. Variables are simply names that refer to objects. Doing y = x doesn’t create a copy of the list – it creates a new variable y that refers to the same object x refers to. This means that there is only one object (the list), and both x and y refer to it.
> 2. Lists are mutable, which means that you can change their content.
>
> ### [How do I copy an object in Python?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-python)
>
> In general, try [`copy.copy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.copy) or [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) for the general case. Not all objects can be copied, but most can.
>
> Some objects can be copied more easily. Dictionaries have a `copy()` method:
>
> `newdict = olddict.copy()`
>
> Sequences can be copied by slicing:
>
> `new_l = l[:]`